# Ordering query objects in django

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-aggregation

I'm trying to order the results of my query in a sort of parent/child manner. I'm wondering if there's an easy way to accomplish this.

Object:

```
Video : [id, parent_id, date]  // where parent_id can be null - meaning it is a 'root' node.
```

Queryset ordering I want:

```
Video 1: [123, null, 01/11]
  Video 2: [111, 123, 02/11]
  Video 3: [144, 123, 04/11]

Video 4: [191, null, 03/11]
  Video 5: [118, 191, 03/11]
  Video 6: [121, 191, 05/11]

Video 7: [411, null, 04/11]

...
```

Is there a way to achieve this sort of parent/ child group ordering in a queryset?

Comment: You can get root nodes and access to children through dot notation: `video.video_set.all()`. Is not enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use this at the template level, you can use the `regroup` template tag to reorder the queryset:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup

```
{% regroup videos by parent_id as group %}
{% for video in group %}
    {{ video.grouper }}
    {% for child in group.list %}{{ child }}{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [django-mptt](http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/), which will solve this problem for you.

More information on MPTT from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPTT)